# Time complexity : Insertion sort with unique key

Tags: sorting, data-structures, time-complexity

I have a random ordered array of 30 elements with only 3 distinct keys (`TRUE`, `FALSE` and `NULL`) that I want to sort using insertion sort. What will be the time complexity? Will it be O(n<sup>2</sup>) assuming worst case or O(n) assuming best case since there are only 3 different keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*n* refers to the size of the array, not the possible elements of the array. Thus, the complexity is the same:

- Worst-case: O(n<sup>2</sup>)
- Best-case: O(n)
- Average-case: O(n<sup>2</sup>)

Having 3 distinct elements will reduce the amount of elements you have to check during the "insertion" phase, but only by a constant factor. This will not change the asymptotic run-time.

For example, in the average-case, instead of insert checking *n* elements, it will check *<sup>n</sup>*/<sub>3</sub> elements. This is better, but not asymptotically.

Comment: It's worth noting the average case is also O(n^2).

Comment: Since it is random ordered array the time complexity should be its worst case complexity. But assuming there are only 3 distinct keys and order doesn't matter for identical keys, will the time complexity change?

Comment: In the worst case, you will still have to do ~ n^2 passes through the array in worst case. Having 3 distinct elements will reduce the amount of elements you check, but not asymptotically.

Comment: One quick question : If all the keys are unique in the array instead of 3 distinct keys what will be the time complexity of the insertion sort? Will it be O(n)?

Comment: Yes. Recall that Insertion sort's best case is when the array is already sorted. If there is only one element in the array, then it can be considered sorted. Therefore this is the best case for insertion sort, so it will be O(n).